# Правильно ли писать статичные методы контроллера?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть роут:

```
 Route::post('/update_send_to_production_event', 'PreorderController@updateSendToProductionEvent');
```

Я написал метод:

```
public static function updateSendToProductionEvent(Request $request): void {
  SendToProduction::dispatch($request->preorder_id, $request->status_id, $request->during);
}
```

Мне сделали замечание, что тут не должно быть `static` так как этот метод не вызовется нигде из кода, кроме маршрутов, а если будет вызываться, то это нарушение принципов **SOLID**.

Корректно ли писать здесь `static`?

Comment: С какой целью здесь надо было писать `static`?

Comment: @u_mulder Я не использую экземпляр класса контроллера.

Comment: ну так где-то в недрах ларавеля разве не создастся экземпляр?

Comment: @u_mulder я не анализировал ядро `Laravel`.  Это не важно, так как та или иная реализация может отличаться от версии. Меня больше интересует принципы написания методов для роутов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все верно, `static` используется для того, чтобы использовать метод не создавая экземпляр класса.

Но Ваш метод предназначен для обработки маршрута - здесь подразумевается, что входящие данные из `Request` будут подготовлены (например данные будут переданы в `Validator`) и далее переданы в метод-обработчик.

Вызов метода `updateSendToProductionEvent` из другого контроллера с "имитацией" `Request` - будет немного не корректным (крайне редко может понадобиться - например для тестов), так как сервер должен работать с конкретными данными.

Принцип `Single responsibility` - подразумевает, что метод используется по своему прямому назначению и отвечает только за одну логику, которая в данном случае является обработкой входящего запроса и проверкой данных (что логично так как запрос `POST`) с последующим проксированием в метод-обработчик. Поэтому можно засчитать за нарушение, если вызывать его из другого класса.

Если предполагается использование этого метода в других классах, то разделите вашу логику на 2 метода. Первый `non static` будет принимать `Request` и проверять данные и второй  `static` который будет уже непосредственно работать с подготовленными данными.

Краткий вывод - в конкретном примере `static` не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

> этот метод не вызовется нигде из кода, кроме маршрутов, а если будет вызываться, то это нарушение принципов `SOLID`.

Не вижу проблемы в том чтобы вызвать этот метод из другой части программы, с какой бы целью это не производилось.

Не вижу в этом нарушения принципов `SOLID`, ведь если мы сделаем вызов этого метода из "роута" и из другой части кода (имитируя или "проксируя" из другого места `Request`) - поведение метода и результат всегда будет в одном виде который продекларирован заголовком и реализацией метода.
Получается даже наоборот - `принцип единой ответственности метода будет соблюдён`.

Другое дело что вариантов реализаций вашего кода есть несколько и более красивая была бы реализация такая, где метод производящий конкретное действие находится в классе по работе с соответствующей сущностью, а метод контроллера будет выступать лишь как входная точка, которая лишь передаст управление дальше соответствующему методу класса.

Таким образом мы добьёмся дополнительного уровня абстракции, добавится прослойка.

В вашем случае меньше абстракции - но это не является ошибкой, если вы в этой абстракции и не нуждаетесь.